# Windows 10 sharing app settings between devices with same account

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

Is there any possibility to do this ?

I'd like to identify the user and one easy way is to save GUID that is automatically visible on other devices with same MS Account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use roaming settings for this

```
var roamingSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;

// Create a simple setting

roamingSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello World";

// Read data from a simple setting

Object value = roamingSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];

if (value == null)
{
     // No data
}
else
{
     // Access data in value
}

// Delete a simple setting

roamingSettings.Values.Remove("exampleSetting");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

Oh my...
I spent half a day reading forums and suddenly found an answer, right after posting SO Queston :( Sorry.

Microsoft has good buch of Win10 samples, and one of them describes ApplicationData.Roaming -

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData

Any file that is put to this folder is synced to other devices automatically.